# Appendix Equation Numbering (IA.1), (IA.2)

Tags: equations, numbering

How do I number equations in appendix as (IA.1), (IA.2)... I want equations in main document to be numbered globally and then equations in appendix to be numbered globally, with the numbering restarting in the appendix.

Comment: What does `I` and `A` in `IA.1` mean?

Comment: I is internet and A is appendix

Comment: And how do you create your appendices? Do you call `\appendix` and then `\chapter{An appendix}`? Do you use the [`appendix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix)? Does `I` come from some other counter within the document or some other reference? Or is it just `I`... for `I`nternetz...?

Comment: Is there just one appendix chapter, or are there also appendices "B", "C", etc.? If it's the latter, should equations in those chapters be labelled "IB.1", "IB.2", ..., "IC.1", "IC.2", ...? Separately, are you willing to contemplate a dash (or some other visual separator) between "I" and "A", "B", etc? And, do you use the `amsmath` package? (This is important for they way equation labels are constructed.)

Answer (score 8):

Without the need for packages (even though you might be using the [`appendix` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix)), just update the way `\theequation` is displayed. That is, change it to `I<appendix>.<equation>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}

\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{I\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful for me as I needed a similar thing, though with `\documentclass[man]{apa7}`. For me, changing the `renewcommand{...}` to `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theappendix\arabic{equation}}` did the trick!